# ASP.NET Core as Windows service wwwroot location

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dnx, kestrel-http-server

I have a windows-service application containing ASP .NET Core

The project.json has 2 commans:

```
"commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "service": "MyAppNamespace"
}
```

The entry point class:

```
public class Program : ServiceBase
{
    IApplication _application;

    public Program(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {

    }

    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Run(this);
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        var configProvider = new MemoryConfigurationProvider();
        configProvider.Add("server.urls", "http://*:80");

        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .Add(configProvider)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();

        _application = new WebHostBuilder(config)
            .UseServer("Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel")
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build()
            .Start();

        // my stuff bellow
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _application?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

After publishing project we have this folder structure:

```
approot
logs
wwwroot
```

Next I start my application from console

```
dnx.exe -p "C:\MyProject\approot\src\MyProject" service
```

But instead of using webroot directory from "C:\MyProject\wwwroot" we have same as project.json i.e. "C:\MyProject\approot\src\MyProject"

If I start application by "web" command like this:

```
dnx.exe -p "C:\MyProject\approot\src\MyProject" web
```

then all works as should, but of course my entry point was ignored and I cannot execute my stuff, neither run as service

project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "MicroORM": "1.0.7",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-rc1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Npgsql": "3.0.5",
    "ObjectPool": "1.0.0"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls=http://*:80",
    "service": "MikroBill"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx46": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Data": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.ServiceProcess": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your entire project.json file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Shorter Answer

We can add the `webroot` key to our `MemoryConfigurationProvider`:

```
configProvider.Add("webroot", "relative-path-to-web-root");
```

Or we can register our hosting.json file with the `ConfigurationBuilder`:

```
config.AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true)
```

## Example

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    var configProvider = new MemoryConfigurationProvider();
    configProvider.Add("server.urls", "http://localhost:5000");
    configProvider.Add("webroot", "./../../../my-root");

    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .Add(configProvider)
        .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true)
        .Build();

    _application = new WebHostBuilder(config)
        .UseServer("Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel")
        .UseStartup<Program>()
        .Build()
        .Start();
}
```

## Longer Answer

When we pass a `ConfigurationBuilder` into the `WebHostBuilder` constructor, we no longer get the default settings for free. This is the empty `WebHostBuilder` constructor.

```
public WebHostBuilder()
    : this(config: new ConfigurationBuilder().Build()) { }
```

It probably uses the `WebHostConfiguration.GetDefault` method, which adds the `hosting.json` file for us.

```
public static IConfiguration GetDefault(string[] args)
{
    // code omitted for clarity

    var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddInMemoryCollection(defaultSettings)
        .AddJsonFile(WebHostDefaults.HostingJsonFile, optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix:
           WebHostDefaults.EnvironmentVariablesPrefix);

    // code omitted for clarity

    return configBuilder.Build();
}
```

We can do the same thing in our code. [Here is a sample for good measure.](https://github.com/bigfont/StackOverflow/tree/master/AspNetWindowsService)

Comment: I have one more option. If we simple copy wwwroot to the project directory it would work, but I not really like this approach

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106651/discussion-between-shaun-luttin-and-miles).